# Push notifications with Android in Phonegap and WebIntent

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, cordova

I have successfully implemented the WebIntent plugin so that when a push notification is received and the app is not active; when a user taps it the app opens up at the index page and displays a modal with relevant message.

This is the webintent code to get the route which displays the modal message:

```
        window.plugins.webintent.hasExtra('com.parse.Data',
            function(has) {
                if (has) {
                    // has is true iff it has the extra
                    console.error('extra was gettable');
                    window.plugins.webintent.getExtra('com.parse.Data',
                        function(data) {

                            var data = JSON.stringify(data),
                                data = data.replace(/[\\]/g, '').replace(/[\/]/g, ''),
                                data = data.replace(/"(.+)"/, "$1"),
                                data = $.parseJSON(data);

                            Parse.history.navigate('notification/' + data.pid, true);

                            // if user authenticated already just route 
                            // if not authenticate then route...
                            //AppUser.authenticate();
                        }, function() {
                            // There was no extra supplied.
                            console.error('extra was NOT gettable');
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    console.error('extra was NOT supplied');
                }
            }, function() {
                // Something really bad happened.
                console.error('Something really bad happened');
            }
        );
```

I am using the Parse SDK and followed this blog post to get this case working:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/10/10/PhoneGap-Parsecom-and-Push-Notifications#c1E596902-EB43-70CE-3E0A44563B5EC611

This is my AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.leotech.slcompanion" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Hello_World" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
</manifest>
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to trigger an action in the app when a push notification is received whilst the app is already active.

So regardless of where the user is in the application the modal route should be triggered to display a relevant message.

Comment: Add a callback when you register with gcm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can react to a notification by listening for [PhoneGap's "resume" event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume):

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function(){
  // check for your webintent and perform your action
}, true);
```

This works when the app is in the foreground, despite the documentation suggesting it's background only.